# OpenVPN v3 Dbus client not receiving all signals

Tags: glib, dbus, openvpn, gio, gjs

I'm writing an Applet for Linux Mint/Cinnamon to manage OpenVPN v3 connections.

In order to avoid synchronous calls that can cause the DE to stutter or freeze, I'm writing a simple DBus client using the `Gio` and `GLib` libraries provided by [GJS](https://gjs.guide/). This allows an asynchronous, partly event-driven approach and should avoid any nasty side effects. It's my first time using any of these technologies but the OpenVPN DBus API is [pretty well documented](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/blob/master/docs/dbus/dbus-overview.md) and the API docs for [Gio and GLib](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/) are also good.

The problem I have is with signal subscriptions, specifically the `StatusChange` signal published by the `net.openvpn.v3.sessions` service. A bunch of these signals are published whenever a connection is established, paused, resumed or closed. Most of the signals are picked up by my subscribed listener, but not all of them. In particular, I don't receive the `session closed` signal.

Using the `dbus-monitor` commandline tool, you can see all the `StatusChange` signals published when a connection is established (7 signals) and then closed (2 signals):

```text
$ sudo dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',interface='net.openvpn.v3.sessions',member='StatusChange'"
...

// Connect:
signal time=1625847543.107244 sender=:1.891 -> destination=:1.892 serial=2745 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 3
   uint32 27
   string "session_path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49, backend_pid=42584"
signal time=1625847543.116395 sender=:1.891 -> destination=:1.892 serial=2762 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 3
   uint32 17
   string "session_path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49 backend_busname=net.openvpn.v3.backends.be42585 backend_path=/net/openvpn/v3/backends/session"
signal time=1625847543.117286 sender=:1.891 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2764 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 2
   uint32 2
   string "config_path=/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/9dd3fa9cxb6e0x48acxaa1ex566312bea232"
signal time=1625847543.638519 sender=:1.891 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2775 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 2
   uint32 2
   string "config_path=/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/9dd3fa9cxb6e0x48acxaa1ex566312bea232"
signal time=1625847543.638533 sender=:1.891 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2776 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 2
   uint32 6
   string ""
signal time=1625847543.735357 sender=:1.891 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2777 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 2
   uint32 6
   string ""
signal time=1625847543.974784 sender=:1.891 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2778 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 2
   uint32 7
   string ""


// Disconnect:
signal time=1625847646.846790 sender=:1.891 -> destination=:1.892 serial=2834 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 3
   uint32 28
   string "Session closed"
signal time=1625847646.848262 sender=:1.891 -> destination=:1.892 serial=2839 path=/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49; interface=net.openvpn.v3.sessions; member=StatusChange
   uint32 3
   uint32 19
   string ""
```

The following code creates a subscription that, as far as I can tell, should receive the same signals as above. Note I'm using the lower-level approach to obtain a subscription here; the subscription is made on the global connection, rather than via a `DBusProxy` for a specific object path. I've tried both approaches (same result) but the following should be a closer analogue to the `dbus-monitor` command above.

```js
    subscribeToStatusChangeSignals() {
        this.statusChangeHandlerId = Gio.DBus.system.signal_subscribe(
            'net.openvpn.v3.sessions',
            'net.openvpn.v3.sessions',
            'StatusChange',
            null,
            null,
            Gio.DBusSignalFlags.NONE,
            this._handleGlobalStatusChangeSignal
        );
    }

    _handleGlobalStatusChangeSignal(connection, sender, path, iface, signal, params) {
        let container = params.deep_unpack();
        let statusMajorCode = container[0];
        let statusMinorCode = container[1];
        let statusMajor = lookupStatusMajor(statusMajorCode);  // lookup the corresponding text
        let statusMinor = lookupStatusMinor(statusMinorCode);  // from something resembling an enum
        let message = container[2];

        global.log(`Received StatusChange signal
            path:         [${path}]
            Status Major: [${statusMajorCode} - ${statusMajor}]
            Status Minor: [${statusMinorCode} - ${statusMinor}]
            Message:      [${message}]`
        );
    }
```

The resulting logs when opening and closing the same connection as before:

```text
// Connect:
Cjs-Message: 18:19:03.117: JS LOG: [LookingGlass/info] Received StatusChange signal
            path:         [/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49]
            Status Major: [2 - CONNECTION]
            Status Minor: [2 - CFG_OK]
            Message:      [config_path=/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/9dd3fa9cxb6e0x48acxaa1ex566312bea232]
Cjs-Message: 18:19:03.638: JS LOG: [LookingGlass/info] Received StatusChange signal
            path:         [/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49]
            Status Major: [2 - CONNECTION]
            Status Minor: [2 - CFG_OK]
            Message:      [config_path=/net/openvpn/v3/configuration/9dd3fa9cxb6e0x48acxaa1ex566312bea232]
Cjs-Message: 18:19:03.639: JS LOG: [LookingGlass/info] Received StatusChange signal
            path:         [/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49]
            Status Major: [2 - CONNECTION]
            Status Minor: [6 - CONN_CONNECTING]
            Message:      []
Cjs-Message: 18:19:03.735: JS LOG: [LookingGlass/info] Received StatusChange signal
            path:         [/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49]
            Status Major: [2 - CONNECTION]
            Status Minor: [6 - CONN_CONNECTING]
            Message:      []
Cjs-Message: 18:19:03.974: JS LOG: [LookingGlass/info] Received StatusChange signal
            path:         [/net/openvpn/v3/sessions/052850e7s915fs483esb3e7s3afb389a2e49]
            Status Major: [2 - CONNECTION]
            Status Minor: [7 - CONN_CONNECTED]
            Message:      []

// Disconnect:
<nada>
```

One pattern i've noticed is that the signals i do receive all have a `null destination` in the `dbus-monitor` output:

```
... sender=:1.891 -> destination=(null destination) ...
```

while the signals I *don't* receive have a specific destination:

```
... sender=:1.891 -> destination=:1.892 ...
```

Presumably these are direct signals intended for a particular recipient, rather than signals broadcast to all interested subscribers, but I haven't found this explained anywhere in the docs.

So the question is, why do I receive some signals but not all? Is this by design, or an issue with `Gio`, or (more likely) an issue with how I'm using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging it appears this behaviour is by design - Signals that carry a destination value are treated as unicast messages. Subscribers other than the intended recipient will only receive such messages if they are configured to `eavesdrop`. Presumably this is the case for `dbus-monitor`.

Source: [DBus Specification (Message Routing)](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-routing)